# Find user by PID in Citrix environment

Tags: sql-server-profiler, citrix

We're running a Citrix farm and I'm trying to track heavy users of our DB, I can get the PID of the process from Sql Profiler but I then need to laboriously search for that PID in each server in the farm - anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Citrix API's (WFAPI) to programmatically enumerate the Citrix Servers (WFEnumerateServers) in your Farm(s) and enumerate all processes (WFEnumerateProcesses). It is of course possible to have the same PID so you need some method to determine the correct one (such as username).
Also note that a PID can be reused and only the combination of PID and starttime makes it unique.